# SQLite Interop DLL Error with ASP5

Tags: c#, sqlite, nhibernate, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am doing an MVC6 project with .NET Framework 4.6. The ORM is NHibernate and I am trying to setup SQLite as the test database. I have installed `System.Data.SQLite` from nuget however I am getting the error

`{"Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"}`

From what I have found, I need to set the copy local property of the sqlite reference to true but there is no way to set it in the project. What should I do to get rid of this error ? Any ideas ?

Comment: I suspect sqlite is referenced in dll-project in your solution. Nuget install sqlite on the executing project also should help.

Answer (score 0):

Try targeting .NET 4.5.1 instead. System.Data.Sqlite does not yet target .NET 4.6

Answer (score 0):

Have just solved this in my VS2015 Community WinForms project by:
1. adding two folders to project root (x86, x84)
2. copying the x86 and x64 interop dll's into these folders (can get these from bin/debug/x86 and x64.
3.  Then "Add Existing Item" to get the interop dll's included in project in respective folder.
4. Right-click on each dll in project folder and choose 'content' and 'allways copy'.

This is all from memory, so adjust accordingly.

Had tried all sorts of other options, none of which worked.